# Layout Group components with special division

Tags: unity-game-engine

When we use `Layout Groups` components in `Unity` editor . it divide our `Layouts` in same sections.

But i want have different size for my `UI's` in vertical or horizontal Groups .

In this image i have 3 UI (red , white and green color) . as you see they have same height size .

Red section that its name is header must have smaller height and also footer

[image]

It must like following image :

[image]

Comment: so you are looking for the Layout Element Component and Content size Fitter ?

Comment: yes i tested them before but i really cant do this work by these components . if you can write me a tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something you want:

[image]

Setup vertical layout group like this:

[image]

You can see there are 3 child objects of `VerticalLayoutGroup` object in hierarchy. **Header**, **Content** and **Footer**. Now on **Content** object, add `LayoutElement` component and set Preferred Height as desired:

[image]

Note: you don't need to add `LayoutElement` on other children if you don't want to give them extra space. They will use rest of space equally.

From [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-LayoutElement.html):

> - First minimum sizes are allocated.
> - If there is sufficient available space, preferred sizes are allocated.
> - If there is additional available space, flexible size is allocated.

Comment: how we can keep header and footer ? if we resize and make content larger after a size header and footer will removed from scene ! ? One thing like Ratio between this ui's

Comment: You increase size of parent (layoutgroup) in that case